# Create checkbox option on checkout page for recurring order payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, recurring

I need a check-box on checkout page for setup recurring payment.

I want to give ability to the user to select option of autorenew or manual renewal of his subscription using woocommerce checkout page. If they select the checkbox, the subscription should autorenew on next interval. If they don't select it, the subscription should be manual.

I have used woocommerce and woocommerce-subscription plugin for this.

Comment: Did you figure out this out?  I'm looking to do something similiar!

Comment: no option in woocommerce for renewal so if you want renewal in site with woocommerce so  please custom the code and make a function for this